# Multiple file reading

Tags: matlab, file-read

I have more than 10,000 csv file in one folder and file names are 0,1,2,3... like that. I would like to read them and write into one file for further processing.I tried this

```
files= dir('C:\result\*.csv');
outs = cell(numel(files),1) 
for i = 1:numel(files)   
out{i} = csvread('%i',2,0) 
end
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Is there an error? If yes, please *edit* your question to include the error.

Comment: allCsv=[]
m=length(files);
for i=1:lenght(files)
    csvdata=csvread([dname,files(i).name],1,0);
    allCsv = [allCsv;csvdata]; % Concatenate vertically
end

this one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading them in as csv files, I would just read in the raw files and write them out again. This will likely be much faster.

```
files = dir('C:\result\*.csv');
filenames = fullfile('C:\result', {files.name});

% Sort the files based on their number
[~, ind] = sort(str2double(regexp(filenames, '[0-9]+(?=\.csv$)', 'match', 'once')));
filenames = filenames(ind);

% Open the file that you want to combine them into
outfile = 'output.csv';
outfid = fopen(outfile, 'wb');

for k = 1:numel(filenames)
    % Open each file
    fid = fopen(filenames{k}, 'rb');

    % Read in contents and remove any trailing newlines
    contents = strtrim(fread(fid, '*char'));

    % Write out the content and add a newline
    fprintf(outfid, '%s\n', contents);

    % Close the input file
    fclose(fid);
end

fclose(outfid);
```

Comment: This works perfectly for other types of files also. Thanks